# Why is my jpa repository returning an object but any methodcall on this object is giving a nullpointer exception?

Tags: java, spring-data

I have this code in my account controller.

```
        Account account = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);
```

The argument comes from the RESTcontroller argument username that receives the string `"henk@gmail.com"`. The reason why it includes the " " is because I used the javascript command JSON.Stringify(username) before sending it to the controller. When you try to stringify a string it adds an extra pair of "".

Now on to my question. How come `accountRepository.findByUsername(username)` with this argument gives back an account (I checked this by printing:)

```
System.out.println("Is account null? " + account == null);
```

But when I call any method on that account (like toString()) it gives a nullpointer exception? It has something to do with the pair of "" that are encompassing the argument henk@gmail.com, but why is this causing the jpa repository to give back this mysterious account object?

The jpa repository is defined like this:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
    Account findByUsername(String username);
    Account findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
    Set<Account> findByAdminIsTrue();
}
```

The account object is defined as this:

```
@Entity
//@JsonIgnoreProperties
//@JsonIdentityInfo(
//        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
//        property = "id",
//        scope = Account.class)
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private boolean admin;
    private boolean enabled;
    private int remainingStatutoryLeaveHours = 240;
    private int remainingNonStatutoryLeaveHours = 60;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<LeaveQuery> leaveQueryList;
//

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<LaborPeriod> laborperiods = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne
    private Person person;

    @Enumerated
    UserRole userRole = UserRole.USER;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public UserRole getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public List<LaborPeriod> getLaborperiods() {
        return laborperiods;
    }

    public void setLaborperiods(List<LaborPeriod> laborperiods) {
        this.laborperiods = laborperiods;
    }

    public List<LeaveQuery> getLeaveQueryList() {
        return leaveQueryList;
    }

    public void setLeaveQueryList(List<LeaveQuery> leaveQueryList) {
        this.leaveQueryList = leaveQueryList;
    }

    public int getRemainingStatutoryLeaveHours() {
        return remainingStatutoryLeaveHours;
    }

    public void setRemainingStatutoryLeaveHours(int remainingStatutoryLeaveHours) {
        this.remainingStatutoryLeaveHours = remainingStatutoryLeaveHours;
    }

    public int getRemainingNonStatutoryLeaveHours() {
        return remainingNonStatutoryLeaveHours;
    }

    public void setRemainingNonStatutoryLeaveHours(int remainingNonStatutoryLeaveHours) {
        this.remainingNonStatutoryLeaveHours = remainingNonStatutoryLeaveHours;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", admin=" + admin +
                ", enabled=" + enabled +
                ", remainingStatutoryLeaveHours=" + remainingStatutoryLeaveHours +
                ", remainingNonStatutoryLeaveHours=" + remainingNonStatutoryLeaveHours +
                ", leaveQueryList=" + leaveQueryList +
                ", laborperiods=" + laborperiods +
                ", person=" + person +
                ", userRole=" + userRole +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Are you sure that your `toString` method is not throwing a NPE?

Comment: You claim calling `toString()` throws NPE but you haven't shown us the complete stack trace.  Without that your question is unanswerable.  Also, identify the line in your code that throws the exception.

Comment: can't you just take my word for it? the stacktrace identified the line `account.toString()` as the source of the nullpointer exception. So there was no need to post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this statement:

```
    account.toString();
```

is the source of the NPE, then there is only one plausible explanation: the value of `account` is `null`.

---

You say that this statement:

```
    System.out.println("Is account null? " + account == null);
```

is telling you that `account` is not null.  Guess what.  **It isn't!**

The precedence of `+` is higher than `==`.  So the statement above is equivalent to:

```
    System.out.println(("Is account null? " + account) == null);
```

which will print `false` irrespective of the value of `account` because concatenating a string and `null` will be a non-null string.

Rerun your program with that statement written as:

```
    System.out.println("Is account null? " + (account == null));
```

Then you can solve the real problem ... which is figuring out why `account` is `null` and how to deal with that.